# Exibir div de acordo com a resolução de tela

Tags: css, html5

Tenho o seguinte script CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .comp {
      background-color: #000000;
      display: block;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="comp">

</div>
```

Funciona perfeitamente o background-color. Mas o que preciso é que a DIV COMP fique invisível quando max-width for maior que 600px; e fique visível quando max-width for menor que 600px;

Comment: Amigo, recomendo usa as medias queries. Leia o link pra entender oque são elas e como vão ajudar vc.                                                         http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/media-queries.html

Answer (score 1):

```
.comp {
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (min-width:600px){
    .comp {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

O que está acontencendo aqui é o seguinte:

- A div terá display:block até atingir a largura mínima de 600px;
- Quando a largura da tela for 601 ou mais, ela terá o display:none;

O mais aconselhável é você partir do principio de [mobile-first](http://tableless.com.br/mobile-first-a-arte-de-pensar-com-foco/) e fazer as alterações somente para telas maiores.